# frameset not working in IE but works fine Mozilla

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Here's the code that works fine in Mozilla but do not works in Internet Explorer. Any idea. Urgency is high.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>
<FRAMESET rows="15%,81%,4%">
  <FRAMESET>
    <FRAME src="header.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
  </FRAMESET>

  <FRAMESET cols="40%,60%">
    <FRAME name="login_menu_frame" src="login_box.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
    <FRAME name="login_body_frame" src="login_page_body.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
  </FRAMESET>

  <FRAMESET>
    <FRAME name="login_footer_frame" src="footer.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
  </FRAMESET>

</FRAMESET>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe some more information about the error or what happens in internet explorer?

Comment: Only the first frame shows up with the header.html file. and not the other html files i embedd in other frames.

Comment: Have you used IE's developer tools to poke around the details? Looked at the console for error messages? Checked if all resources were loaded correctly?

Comment: I can see four frames in IE11, please define "not working in IE".

Comment: @Teemu IE9 - not working.

Comment: @deceze - I've never worked with this HMTL thing. Working around coz my manager asked to do so. And using frames for the same reason. div would have been better. I know. 

Moreover, If I would have been aware with IE's developer tools to poke around the details, I might already been knowing the solution to this problem.

Comment: Umh... "not working" is worth of nothing when you're explaining what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. You could remove the extra `frameset` elements though (i.e. remove all `frameset`s without `rows` or `cols` attribute).

Comment: Thank you.. Thanks a lot @Teemu buddy. Removing the extra frameset worked for both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer. The problem lies in the 
IE is only recoznising the first . So, whatever is placed after that is not being loaded in the page. 
The solution is to put every other frameset in the first  [any other frameset] .

The code that worked is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

  <FRAMESET rows="15%,81%,4%">
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="header.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>


<FRAMESET cols="40%,60%">
<FRAME name="login_menu_frame" src="login_box.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
<FRAME name="login_body_frame" src="login_page_body.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
</FRAMESET>

<FRAMESET>
<FRAME name="login_footer_frame" src="footer.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></FRAME>
</FRAMESET>

</FRAMESET>
  </FRAMESET>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: And now its not working in Mozilla Firefox. Can anyobdy provide a fix so that it supports both Internet Explorer 9 and Mozilla Firefox ?

Comment: Correction: 

Removing extra frameset without any rows or cols attribute worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What's up with the CAPS, copy-pasted this from actual -96 sources found on a floppy? ;-P

Also, try and apply consistent indentation for the tags. Your main frameset tag is directly followed by another (rouge) frameset tag, which missing closing tag..

Example usage that clearly indicates which elements are contained inside each other for quick mismatch spotting:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>HTML Frames</title>
  </head>

  <frameset rows="10%,80%,10%">
    <frame name="top" src="/html/top_frame.htm" />
    <frame name="main" src="/html/main_frame.htm" />
    <frame name="bottom" src="/html/bottom_frame.htm" />

    <noframes>
      <body>
        <h1>Your browser does not support frames.</h1>
      </body>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>

</html>
```